# How does the Linux kernel detect if a memory address was modified to implement COW?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, copy-on-write

Source code Here:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 void main() {
     int *a = malloc(sizeof(int));
     *a = 11;
     int b = 22;//on the stack

     int pid = fork();

     if (pid == 0) {
         printf("pid=%d, a = %d, &a=%p\n", getpid(), *a, a);
         printf("pid=%d, b = %d, &b=%p\n", getpid(), b, &b);
         getchar();
         *a = 33;// ===========cow=========happend here=====
         b = 44;
         printf("pid=%d, a = %d, &a=%p\n", getpid(), *a, a);
         printf("pid=%d, b = %d, &b=%p\n", getpid(), b, &b);
     } else {
         printf("pid=%d, a = %d, &a=%p\n", getpid(), *a, a);
         printf("pid=%d, b = %d, &b=%p\n", getpid(), b, &b);
     }
     pause();
 }
```

Here is the gdb disassemble of that line which writing **33** to **a**,
I set a breakpoint here. and start this program. Then using *crash* to see the physical address of **a**

```
  >│0x40073a <main+154>     movl   $0x2c,-0x20(%rbp)  //copy on write happend here                                                                                                                              │
   │0x400741 <main+161>     mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rax                                                                                                                                 │
   │0x400745 <main+165>     mov    (%rax),%ebx
```

The linear address of **a** is **0x602010**, so using *vtop*, I got this:

We can see that they are point to the same physical address of **2a683010**

```
    PID: 6468
COMMAND: "a.out"
   TASK: ffff88007c317300  [THREAD_INFO: ffff880016728000]
    CPU: 0
  STATE: TASK_TRACED|TASK_WAKEKILL
crash> vtop 0x602010
VIRTUAL     PHYSICAL
602010      2a683010

   PML: 24e6f000 => 2409c067
   PUD: 2409c000 => 7144067
   PMD: 7144018 => 19847067
   PTE: 19847010 => 800000002a683065
  PAGE: 2a683000



    PID: 6464
COMMAND: "a.out"
   TASK: ffff880036992280  [THREAD_INFO: ffff880014e38000]
    CPU: 0
  STATE: TASK_TRACED|TASK_WAKEKILL
crash> vtop 0x602010
VIRTUAL     PHYSICAL
602010      2a683010

   PML: 36df9000 => 3a654067
   PUD: 3a654000 => 1a71a067
   PMD: 1a71a018 => 18f2a067
   PTE: 18f2a010 => 800000002a683065
  PAGE: 2a683000
```

After type **ni** in gdb(which changed the value of a to 33), using *vtop* again. I can see one of the process's physical address has changed.

```
crash> vtop 0x602010
VIRTUAL     PHYSICAL
602010      5d755010

   PML: 24e6f000 => 2409c067
   PUD: 2409c000 => 7144067
   PMD: 7144018 => 19847067
   PTE: 19847010 => 800000005d755067
  PAGE: 5d755000



crash> vtop 0x602010
VIRTUAL     PHYSICAL
602010      2a683010

   PML: 36df9000 => 3a654067
   PUD: 3a654000 => 1a71a067
   PMD: 1a71a018 => 18f2a067
   PTE: 18f2a010 => 800000002a683065
  PAGE: 2a683000
```

My question is what happend when cpu execute

```
movl   $0x2c,-0x20(%rbp)
```

How did the kernel know that it is changing a shared memory, so a coping is needed to perform before writing? I am guessing it is using something like page fault interrupt. But I did not found any interrupt related about this.

Please provide the source code of kernel if the kernel is in charge for this.

Comment: *please provide the source code of kernel if the kernel is in charge for this.* https://github.com/torvalds/linux

Comment: @AndrewHenle nice one :-)

Comment: I think this one is better then github https://code.woboq.org/linux/linux/

Comment: I think wikipedia has the answer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write#Copy-on-write_in_virtual_memory_management "Copy-on-write can be implemented by notifying the MMU that certain pages in the process's address space are read-only. When data is written to these pages, the MMU raises an exception which is handled by the kernel, which allocates new space in physical memory and makes the page being written correspond to that new location in physical memory." Brillant stuff.

Comment: Also I'd link to https://people.redhat.com/anderson/crash_whitepaper/ on the question, many people like me might not know it :-)

Comment: There we go: https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=k_ocKY0iegsC&pg=PA135&lpg=PA135&dq=linux+kernel+fork+copy+on+write&source=bl&ots=VhHLKaqxLA&sig=t1-9uzfjo8qHQxvdA9Y6grDebWU&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYp_Gf14bNAhWCGaYKHc6PBHMQ6AEIaDAJ#v=onepage&q=linux%20kernel%20fork%20copy%20on%20write&f=false

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13392931/copy-on-write-in-linux

Comment: How about this one: https://code.woboq.org/linux/linux/mm/memory.c.html#3196

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My question is what happend when cpu execute
>
> movl   $0x2c,-0x20(%rbp)
>
> How did the kernel know that it is changing a shared memory, so a coping is needed to perform before writing? I am guessing it is using something like page fault interrupt. But I did not found any interrupt related about this.

This is achieved with the cooperative effort of the processor and the OS.

**The processor side:**

When the CPU executes such an instruction:

> movl $0x2c,-0x20(%rbp)

i.e. fetching the address stored in %rbp register and adding an offset -x20 to it, then issuing a memory access to it(movl).

Upon committing the memory access, the processor will walks the hardware page table(well, in most case, it is short cut by visiting the TLB, but I just talk in fundamental principle here). The page tables, of course, should be setup beforehand by the OS.

Suppose the processor makes its way to the final level page table, and just finds that the corresponding page table entry(will call it **pte** for short for the rest of this answer) for that very address
suggests the page containing that address content is NOT in memory!(It just consults a specific page flag of that pte), then, depending on processor architecture, a hardware exception is raised ! According to Intel terminology, it categorizes such type of exception in to **fault**, and you must frequently hear the term **'page fault'**(a kind of exception that could be fixed and the execution could be resumed as if there was no such exception had happened at all !)

**The OS side:**

Then we move up the stack into the OS domain.  During booting process, the OS will setup an exception and interrupt handler table(in x86 jargon we call it **IDT**), and will register it to the processor.

Then upon this page fault happening, the pre-setup handler is executed by the processor(technically, the processor shall save the CPU context first, like pushing the cs and rip registers, the rflags register, etc).

The handler could be divided into the arch-specific part (where the OS will further do some hardware related jobs, like saving more registers, call arch-specific hook, determine whether the page fault is allowed? etc) and the arch-independent part(the page faulting logic), so no surprise the handler entry point is arch dependent.

For Linux on x86, the arch-specific part is located in  **arch/x86/entry/entry_64.S** (for 64 bit) and the do_page_fault() C function in **arch/x86/mm/fault.c**. Then in do_page_fault(), it will call arch-independent C function handle_mm_fault(), which locates in the core MM code at **mm/memory.c**.

And for this question, in handle_mm_fault(), do_wp_page() handles the COW logic. Basically, handle_mm_fault() just walks the page table of the faulting address and finds out that it is a write protect page(present, but write flag is not set), so it calls do_wp_page() to allocate a new page.